# Using drag and drop in a vm-clarity tree

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, vmware-clarity

I have an Angular application that is using Clarity and in that app, we use a Tree component to display a list of items, which works fine. But we want to be able to drag and drop items in that tree up and down the tree to change the position of a tree node.

I've been looking around for an example of this, but so far I cannot see if Clarity's drag and drop functionality can be added to a tree.

Does anyone know if this can be set up? If so is there an example of how this is done?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Clarity does not have this out of the box, but there is a design spec. https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1821

There is a person doing some work on it, but it isn't done. Here is one example to show a possible starting point https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/4204.